# How can I center a figure with caption?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have this HTML and CSS:

```css
figure {
       display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
 
}

  figure img {
         display:block;
         margin:0 auto;
         border-radius: 100%;
 }

figcaption {
        display:block;
        padding:8px;

 }
```

```html
<figure>
    <img src="me.jpg" alt="Author Of The Blog" height="200" width="200">
    <caption>Me and the co-author of this blog, Pepe</caption>
</figure>
```

My problem is that the figure is not centered, how can I do that? I also need to center the caption along with the photo. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you set `figure` display property to `inline-block` for reason. If so all you need to do is to set parent container `text-align` property to `center`:

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

figure {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
figure img {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
figcaption {
    display:block;
    padding:8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Author Of The Blog" height="200" width="200">
        <caption>Me and the co-author of this blog, Pepe</caption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, thx a lot. I though that mybe I could go around this without wrapping the figure in a separate div.

Comment: You can. But in this case you need to set `figure` to `display: block`. Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2cm6dgot/

Comment: Yes, you were right again, the effect is the same if I change "inline-block" with "block". Can the caption be modified in any way (font-weight, family etc)?

Comment: Weird thing, it didn't worked. I will keep on trying. Thx for the help.